# Multiple Firestore connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

I need help regarding tackling this scenario where I need to connect to multiple firestores in different google cloud projects.

Right now. I am using NestJs to retrieve data from my Firestore. Connecting to it using a JSON key generated from a Service Account.

I am planning to make this primary Firestore store data that would tell what database should the app connect to. However, I'm oblivious to how can I do the switching of service accounts/JSON keys. Since, from what I understood so far, is 1 JSON key is for 1 Firestore. I also think that it's not a good practice to store those JSON key files.

What are my possible options here?

Comment: Hi @Hexxed, have you considered using [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/create-secret)?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB thanks for the info. Yep, I'm already looking into that. I'm still pretty new to this and was assigned to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/create-secret) to store your Firestore configurations. To start:

1. Create a secret by navigating to Cloud Console > Secret Manager. You could also click this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager).
2. You should enable the Secret Manager API if you haven't done so.
3. Click Create Secret.
4. Fill up the Name, for e.g. `FIRESTORE`.
5. On Secret value, you could either upload the JSON file or paste the Secret Value.
6. Click Create Secret.

After creating a secret, go to your project and install the [@google-cloud/secret-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/secret-manager):

```
npm i @google-cloud/secret-manager
```

then initiate it like this:

```
import {SecretManagerServiceClient} from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
```

You could now use the stored configuration on your project. See code below for reference:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { getFirestore, serverTimestamp, addDoc, collectionGroup, collection, query, where, getDoc, getDocs, doc, updateDoc, setDoc, arrayRemove, arrayUnion, onSnapshot, orderBy, limit, increment } from "firebase/firestore";

const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

// Must follow expected format: projects/*/secrets/*/versions/*
// You can always use `latest` if you want to use the latest uploaded version.
const name = 'projects/PROJECT-ID/secrets/FIRESTORE/versions/latest'
  
async function accessSecretVersion() {
  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
      name: name,
    });
      
  // Extract the payload as a string.
  const payload = version?.payload?.data?.toString();

  // WARNING: Do not print the secret in a production environment - this
  const config = JSON.parse(payload);

  const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: config.apiKey,
    authDomain: config.authDomain,
    databaseURL: config.databaseURL,
    projectId: config.projectId,
    storageBucket: config.storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: config.messagingSenderId,
    appId: config.appId,
    measurementId: config.measurementId
  });

  const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

  const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}
  
accessSecretVersion();
```

You should also create `Secrets` on your different projects and make sure that each project's IAM permissions are set to access each other. You can easily choose/switch your Firestore by modifying the secret name here:

```
const name = 'projects/PROJECT-ID/secrets/FIRESTORE/versions/latest'
```

For convenience, you can identically name the secrets given that they are different projects. You can then just change the `PROJECT-ID` which you want to access the Firestore.

> - [**Creating and accessing secrets**](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets)
> - [**Managing Secrets**](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secrets)
> - [**Managing Secret Versions**](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secret-versions)
> - [**API Reference Documentation**](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/secretmanager/latest/index.html)

You may also want to checkout [**Secret Manager Best Practices**](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/best-practices).